# Disable Asset Pipeline/Sprockets Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gruntjs, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I cannot seem to find a way to disable the Asset Pipeline in Rails 4.1. I see a lot of information for Rails 3.2.

I want to use Grunt/GulpJs and bower to handle all of my assets and I cannot seem to find something for this. Rather I find a decent amount but most of it doesn't apply to me or is broken.

There is the [`half-pipe` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/half-pipe). However half-pipe relies on Rails 4.0 and I'm on Rails 4.1 and I can't find where to force a Gem to install in different version of Rails, if that's even possible.

This question expanded into a few more questions than I intended. Basically I just need to know how to disable the Asset Pipeline, barring that how to integrate GruntJS.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can disable the asset pipeline in `config/application.rb` by adding the following line to it :

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

You could also turn off asset pipeline while creating a new rails application by passing the --skip-sprockets option to it:

```
rails new myappname --skip-sprockets
```

Comment: So it is as simple as that? Then I can just use grunt to build my files and serve those in my layout partials and be good?

Comment: I have never used grunt so can't comment on that part but yes you can disable sprockets as simple as that.

Comment: Basically Grunt just outputs your files minified/concatenated/compiled etc similar to what the pipeline does but with other benefits and more flexibility, not to mention I understand it. 

If you wouldn't mind answering one more question. Is there anyway to install a gem that has a different version requirement? I have a gem that requires 4.0 but I am using 4.1 because a different gem uses it.

Comment: Tricky. Does it say that it will only work with 4.0 or it's a minimum requirement? If it says only with 4.0 then you can think about downgrading.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest..I forked the gem and removed the 4.0 requirement. It's Half-pipe which according to the documentation is little more than a generator for using Grunt so in theory it shouldn't break anything or depend on Rails at all. In the video explaining it the only Rails specific function is commenting out Sprockets. Thank you by the way you've been very helpful.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :) You educated me little bit about Grunt JS. Will surely take a look at it.

Comment: I actually prefer GulpJs because it requires less configuration and is quicker to execute I'm moving from Laravel which is completely hands off when it comes to assets to Rails and I just wanted an easy way to use my own assets without letting Rails touch them and Half-pipe seemed like a good fit though now I wonder if it's needed at all. Thanks again!

Comment: Will this prevent generating assets while I generate a new controller?

Comment: Not working. Not sure what else to say other than it's Rails 4.2.5.

Answer (score 20):

Add this to your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.enabled = false

config.generators do |g|
  g.assets false
end
```

This will disable the asset pipeline and it will prevent the cli generator from creating assets when generating a scaffold.

Answer (score 0):

in Rails 4, just deleting `config/initializers/assets.rb` does the trick.