# Heroku and Precompiled Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, assets

I have a Rails 4 app. One of my javascript assets uses ruby to get all Users.

A problem arises when I try to upload to heroku. It says that it cannot precompile that asset because the database does not yet exist. What can I do short of removing that asset, uploading to heroku to migrate the database, and then putting it back?

Thanks!

Comment: You can disable assets pipeline for initial deploy, than enable it and redeploy. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22572676/1214335

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Compile assets locally**

To solve this chicken and egg problem with the database in deploy, do not invoke precompile in production, precompile on development machine for production prior to push. With a functional code base pushed, you can run "$heroku db:xxx" commands on Heroku.

1. Turn off precompile assets in production.rb:

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

2. Precompile assets for production on development machine:

```
$bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

3. Now your code glob will include your precompiled assets, so push it.

```
$heroku push
```

On deploy to Heroku, you're looking for this line:

```
    -----> Preparing Rails asset pipeline
           Detected manifest.yml, assuming assets were compiled locally
```

4. At this point you can create your production database on Heroku

```
$heroku db:migrate
```

I think these steps will solve your problem. Please let me know.

**Caveat**

Once you disable precompile, you will have to remember to always precompile for production on your dev system prior to deploy to production.

**Javascript compilation into asset pipeline**

Since you're specifically speaking of js precompile, And I haven't tried this, but it seems these types of precompile js-specific lines should also be commented out in production.rb if you have them. There are the same type of js directives in assets. rb, again I don't know if these need to be cleared or not. (*The main point is to do a local asset precompile, before the push to Heroku.*)

```
  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( xxxx.js )
```

**Heroku docs**

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compiling-assets-locally