# How do I completely remove all references to application.js and application.css in a Rails app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working in Rails 4.2.4 to deploy a very simple Web API. This interface does not require JavaScript or CSS, so the requests for `application.js` and `application.css` are just generating log spam and increasing response times. I have tried [disabling assets and skipping sprockets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22572676/577298), but the pages served by the app continue to reference `application.js` and `application.css`, even in my "Hello, world!" controller generated from the [Getting Started Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running).

How can I permanently disable references to these non-existent, unrequired files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` to only have the following content:

```
<%= yield %>
```

In other words, remove the `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags.  There are several other ways to achieve your objective, but this might be the easiest.